# Changes in SelectedItem of ComboBox alter ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ComboBox and a DataGrid in my XAML:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFamily}" ItemsSource="{Binding FamilyList}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding FamilyInfoGrid}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This is my viewmodel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Family> _familyList;
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Family> FamilyList
    {
        get { return _familyList; }
    }

    private Family _selectedFamily;
    public Family SelectedFamily
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedFamily;
        }
        set
        {
            _familyInfoGrid.Clear();
            _familyInfoGrid.Add(value.Kid);
            _familyInfoGrid.Add(value.Parent2);
            _familyInfoGrid.Add(value.Parent1);
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _familyInfoGrid = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    public ObservableCollection<Person> FamilyInfoGrid
    {
        get { return _familyInfoGrid; }
        set { _familyInfoGrid = value; RaisePropertyChangedEvent(); }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        var fam1 = new Family("Smith", new Person("Jim", 31), new Person("Eve", 29), new Person("Tom", 2));
        var fam2 = new Family("Miller", new Person("Joe", 35), new Person("Sue", 33), new Person("Kim", 8));
        _familyList = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Family>(new ObservableCollection<Family>() { fam1, fam2 } );
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

which means the DataGrid always gets updated to the currently selected item of the combobox - as it should.

This my model:

```
public class Family
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person Kid { get; set; }
    public Person Parent1 { get; set; }
    public Person Parent2 { get; set; }

    public Family(string name, Person parent1, Person parent2, Person kid)
    {
        Name = name;  Parent1 = parent1; Parent2 = parent2; Kid = kid;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}


public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name; Age = age;
    }
}
```

The problem is that changes that are made within the DataGrid are stored in the _familyList, but I want the _familyList to be immutable and only be able to edit (and use) the current fields of the DataGrid temporarily (so `Mode=OneWay` is not an option either).

Comment: A bit unclear for me: Is datagrid IsReadOnly="True" what you need? Or do you want the user to be able to temporarily edit the selected item, but the changes to be discarded when the item is unselected?

Comment: yes @kkirk, I would like the user to be able to temporarily edit the selected item, but changes to be discarded if item is unselected.

Comment: What's the point of being able to edit the data then? What are you indending to do with the edited data?

Comment: I would like to execute another function based on the datagrid content whose results will be displayed in the view and the user should be able to change the data and see the effect on the function temporarily.

Comment: @mm8 This is a contrived example of course. In my real example I am saving data from a SQL database into the ReadOnlyObservableCollection when the window loads. However, I do not want to request the data from the database at every getter of SelectedItem of the combobox.

Comment: No. Why would you do that? Clone the in-memory collection and bind to the clone. Then your original data is preserved in the original collection.

Comment: Sorry, but I am new to the mvvm and wpf world. I replaced `public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Family> FamilyList { get { return _familyList; } }` with `public ObservableCollection<Family> FamilyList { get { return new ObservableCollection<Family>(_familyList); } }`. But how do I now access the original collection in the view? I guess the ComboBox is binding to a clone now but the result is the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mm8 I managed to find a solution. The currently selected item of the combobox has to be a "deep copied":

```
public Family SelectedFamily
{
    set
    {
        var fam = new Family(
            new string(value.Name.ToCharArray()),
            new Person(value.Parent1.Name, value.Parent1.Age),
            new Person(value.Parent2.Name, value.Parent2.Age),
            new Person(value.Kid.Name, value.Kid.Age));
        _familyInfoGrid.Clear();
        _familyInfoGrid.Add(fam.Kid);
        _familyInfoGrid.Add(fam.Parent2);
        _familyInfoGrid.Add(fam.Parent1);
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent();
    }
}
```